# How to add current and next year to jsDatePick parameters?

Tags: javascript, jquery, date, jquery-plugins, datepicker

I am using the following parameters with [jsDatePick](http://javascriptcalendar.org/). Can someone tell me how to tell it to only display the current and next year without having to use PHP in my JavaScript?

```
datepicker = new JsDatePick({
  dateFormat: "%m/%d/%Y",
  yearsRange: [2013, 2014],
  limitFromToday: true,
  limitToWorkDays: true
});
```

I want to do this dynamically so next year, someone doesn't have to go in and update the code to change it to 2014 and 2015.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this?

```
var thisYear = new Date().getFullYear(),
    nextYear = thisYear + 1;

datepicker = new JsDatePick({
  dateFormat: "%m/%d/%Y",
  yearsRange: [thisYear, nextYear],
  limitFromToday: true,
  limitToWorkDays: true
});
```

Comment: I tried your code, but for some crazy reason, it's only letting me select 2013 and not 2014. Any ideas?

Comment: I've never used JsDatePick so no, sorry. What do you get if you add `alert([thisYear, nextYear]);` to the script?

Comment: Looks like it's some bug with the script. I changed it to 2013, 2015 and it let me select 2014, but not if I defined the second year as 2014. Nice ;)